# What goes wrong when passing a std::sub_match as argument to a std::thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I'm passing a `std::sub_match` as an argument to a `std::thread` (see my example code below). The thread function expects a const string reference. A sub_match can be converted to a string. So everything compiles fine.

But sometimes the function receives the wrong string.
When I convert the sub_match to a string before passing it to the thread it works as expected. What is the difference?

I think this is a race condition as the original sub_match may not exist anymore when the thread executes. But I thought arguments to threads would be copied anyway.
How can I find out which arguments are safe to pass to a thread and which not?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <regex>
#include <unistd.h>

class test_t {
  public:
    test_t(void) {}
    ~test_t(void) {}

    void start(void){
     //-------------------------------------------------
     // Do some memory allocation.
     // The error seems to appear faster with that.
     std::vector<std::string> vec;
     for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
        vec.push_back("test_test_test");
     }
     //-------------------------------------------------

     std::string event = "operating";
     std::smatch match;
     std::regex expr("\\(operating\\)",
         std::regex_constants::icase | 
         std::regex_constants::basic);

     if(std::regex_match(event, match, expr)) {
        std::cout << "start thread" << std::endl;
        m_thread = std::thread(&test_t::thread_func, this, match[1]);              //NOK
//        m_thread = std::thread(&test_t::thread_func, this, match[1].str());        // OK
//        m_thread = std::thread(&test_t::thread_func, this, (std::string)match[1]); // OK
        m_thread.detach();
        std::cout << "thread started" << std::endl;
     }
    }

  private:
    std::thread m_thread;

    void thread_func(const std::string& string) {
     if(string != "operating") {
        std::cout << "ERROR: string: \"" << string << "\"" << std::endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
     } else {
        std::cout << "string: \"" << string << "\"" << std::endl;
     }
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  test_t test;
  while(1) {
    test.start();
    usleep(100);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Compilation Message:

```
Compiled with: g++ --std=c++11 -pthread -o test main.cpp
g++ --version: g++ (SUSE Linux) 4.8.5
```

Expected output:

```
start thread
thread started
string: "operating"
(repeat)
```

Actual output:

```
start thread
thread started
string: "operating"
ERROR: string: "test_test"
```

Comment: `match[1]` returns a const reference, right? So, you should pass it so, with using `std::cref(match[1])`, because `std::thread` moves all its arguments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`operator[]` for `std::smatch` returns `sub_match` which can be treated as pair of iterators to matched characters.

After `regex_match` was called, you can use `operator[]` to access sub-matches as long as  `event` exists. When `event` is deleted (you are not joining your thread, so `start` returns immediately and `event` is destroyed), sub-matches have dangling pointers and should not be accessed.

---

```
m_thread = std::thread(&test_t::thread_func, this, match[1]);
```

this doesn't work because when function goes out of scope, event is deleted and sub-match has dangling pointers.

---

```
m_thread = std::thread(&test_t::thread_func, this, match[1].str());
```

this works because `str()` returns copy of matched string.

---

```
m_thread = std::thread(&test_t::thread_func, this, (std::string)match[1]);
```

this also works because temporary string is created based on sub-match `match[1]`, and temp is passed into thread.

Comment: The parameter of `thread_func` is `const std::string&`, so won't an implicit `std::string` temporary be created?

Comment: `sub_match` has `operator string()`, but in this line `&test_t::thread_func, this, match[1]` this conversion is not performed - `string` from `match[1]` is not created, `thread` takes as third parameter `sub_match`, then inside thread it uses this to get `string`. But probably it is too late to properly read data from `sub_match` into new string. [Here is small example](https://godbolt.org/z/j6mPMY) which shows this behaviour.

Answer (score 4):

From [some docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/match_results):

> Because `std::match_results` holds `std::sub_matches`, each of which is a pair of iterators into the original character sequence that was matched, it's undefined behavior to examine `std::match_results` if the original character sequence was destroyed or iterators to it were invalidated for other reasons.

… and the same page teaches us that `std::smatch` is an alias for `std::match_results<std::string::const_iterator>`.

You'll need to take a copy of the character range referred to by these iterators, and pass that to `std::thread`.

It is true that `thread_func` will already be doing this copy during argument conversion (since the function takes a `const std::string&`, not a `std::sub_match`), but [this occurs *on the thread*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread) by which point it's too late, as your pointers are already [potentially] dangling.

Comment: The parameter of `thread_func` is `const std::string&`, so won't an implicit `std::string` temporary be created?

Comment: @xskxzr Yes but I believe that takes place on the new thread, i.e. [potentially] too late ([ref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread))

Comment: Hah, literally since our interaction did I completely randomly/co-incidentally discover a `std::smatch` dangling pointer bug in my code :D

Comment: @SombreroChicken Creating job security is no mistake :D